# Neglect someone's duties very much

Tags: phrase-request

How we can change the self-made sentence below to imply that they neglected very much:

> - They are neglecting their duties.

I need to emphasize and make the level of negligence bolder.
For me it seems to be idiomatic to say:

> - They are neglecting their duties very much.

Comment: It does not sound idiomatic to me. I would use a single adverb. "Badly" is a good word for this context.  "They are badly neglecting their duties," is common.

Comment: They are **severely** neglecting their duties. Or  **They are grossly neglecting their duties.**

Comment: They are seriously/largely/completely/entirely/totally neglecting their duties.

Comment: [Here is an ngram showing the frequency of these suggestions.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=badly+neglecting%2Cserverely+neglecting%2Cgrossly+neglecting%2Cseriously+neglecting%2Ccompletely+neglecting%2Centirely+neglecting%2Ctotally+neglecting&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbadly%20neglecting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrossly%20neglecting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseriously%20neglecting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompletely%20neglecting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Centirely%20neglecting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctotally%20neglecting%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: How about: **They have utterly failed in their duties.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**neglect** is usually associated with the adverb **badly**. According to [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=badly%20neglected%2C%20badly%20neglecting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbadly%20neglected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbadly%20neglecting%3B%2Cc0), **badly** is used extensively with a passive participle, but very rarely with an active participle.

Here is an example with a passive participle, which is very common:

> If a tree is **badly neglected** from the time of planting it stands small chance of ever reaching any considerable age

Here is an example with an active participle (in a present perfect continuous), which is very rare.

> She took Sean; she'd been badly neglecting her children all morning

I can't find any instances of it being used with a simple past.

It seems that normally, when talking in the active voice (somebody neglects something), neglect is not gradable: you either do something or you neglect to do it.

When talking about something that has been neglected, it is gradable: it can be neglected just a little, or it can be badly neglected. This presumably depends on the number of occasions that somebody neglected to look after it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to emphasise exactly why he neglected his duty, e.g: If it was deliberate act of disobedience you might say:

> He spurned his duty with disregard.

If it was because he didn't care:

> He heedlessly neglected his duty with indifference.

If it's just that he was unreliable:

> His laxness led to a severe neglect of duty.

Also note that there is the legal term: "Grossly negligent". This has a specific legal meaning and in a literary context would probably be used to imply that criminal proceedings could take place.